# create child table function using cursor in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, cursor, plpgsql, create-table

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_child1()
 RETURNS TABLE(sys_user_id integer,
  sys_service_id integer
  ) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 
curr_id CURSOR IS
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id in (3089,3090,3091,3092);
v_id bigint;
BEGIN

OPEN curr_id;
LOOP
FETCH curr_id INTO v_id;
EXIT WHEN not found ;

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (
  sys_user_id integer,
  sys_service_id integer
  id bigint NOT NULL primary key 
)
INHERITS (telemetry_master)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)', 'telemetry_' || v_id);

end loop;

close curr_id;

fetch next from curr_id into v_id;

END

$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: want to create child table that inherit to its parent table through function using cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an explicit cursor in your function. You can use a simple `FOR ... IN ... LOOP.`

It is unclear what you want to return from the function. For example, it can return a readable text about each created table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_child1()
RETURNS SETOF text LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    v_id int;
BEGIN
    FOR v_id IN 3089..3092 LOOP
        EXECUTE format('
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS telemetry_%s (
                sys_user_id integer,
                sys_service_id integer,
                id bigint NOT NULL primary key 
            )
            INHERITS (telemetry_master)', v_id);
        RETURN NEXT format('telemetry_%s created.', v_id);
    END LOOP;
END $BODY$;
```

Use:

```
SELECT create_child1();

      create_child1      
-------------------------
 telemetry_3089 created.
 telemetry_3090 created.
 telemetry_3091 created.
 telemetry_3092 created.
(4 rows)
```

If the `ids` are not consecutive you can use `unnest()`, e.g.:

```
    FOR v_id IN SELECT id FROM unnest(array[3000,3001,3020,3021]) AS id LOOP
```